# Mock a $http.put result of an angular model - unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

I have this test:

Test:

```
describe('Ao iniciar uma entrevista por id', function () {

        it('deve deve utilizar diretorio raiz da aplicacao', inject(function (Questionario) {
            expect(Questionario.urlEntrevistaPorId).toContain(raiz);
        }));

        it('deve atualizar modelo', inject(function (Questionario, $httpBackend) {
            var entrevistaNova = { a: 1, b: 2 };
            $httpBackend.expectPUT(Questionario.urlEntrevistaPorId, { estudoId: idEstudo, entrevistaId: 666 }).respond({
                Entrevista: entrevistaNova,
                PaginaAtual: novaPagina
            });
            Questionario.iniciarEntrevista(666);
            spyOn(Questionario, 'setEntrevista');
            $httpBackend.flush();
            expect(Questionario.setEntrevista).toHaveBeenCalledWith(entrevistaNova, novaPagina);
        }));

    });
```

Model Angular:

```
function iniciarEntrevista(id) {
            var _this = this;
            return $http
                .put(this.urlEntrevistaPorId, { estudoId: idEstudo, entrevistaId: id })
                .success(function (result) {
                    if (result.Iniciada) {
                        _this.setEntrevista(result.Entrevista, result.PaginaAtual);
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }                 
                });
        }
```

Which calls  Questionario.iniciarEntrevista and waits for setEntrevista to be called. But this method is not being called because of the return of the $http.put.

I need result.Iniciada to be true.

How do I mock this?

Comment: try adding the 200 code to the respond. like this: .respond(200,{})

Comment: I find it easier to just mock the $http object with `spyOn($http, 'post').and.returnValue($q.when(myData));`

Comment: It looks like your `if (result.Iniciad)` condition in the response handler could be the problem. You are checking for this property when the response is received, but you don't seem to be passing that property in the mock response data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to use it is to use [$httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend).

You have there some examples also, basically you inject the $httpBackend inside your testing controller, and map it to a request. You have some examples in the link provided, and I think it is straight forward from here.

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.jeremyzerr.com/angularjs-backend-less-development-using-httpbackend-mock) with a plunker link in it also.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

It was just add the line Iniciada : true on $httpBackend.expectPUT

Thanks everyone!